# Conductive welding primer on fabric

Tags: soldering, conductive, fabric

I saw the discussions about conductive fabric with the links to lessemf.com and others. I'd like to get anyone's thoughts about painting a schematic on cloth using welding conductive primer such as SEM copper weld-through primer (Product Code #:  SEM40783) that I found at http://www.nationaltoolwarehouse.com. Since that works for welding, would it work for soldering wires to it?
Thanks,
Don

Comment: Does it have any constituent which would bond it to the material? I.e. Why would it not simply fall off after a few minutes?

Answer (score 1):

There are conductive glues and silicones available like [this one](http://www.henkel.com/fullproductlist-electronics.htm?countryCode=us&BU=industrial&parentredDotUID=productfinder&redDotUID=201200000ZHU&categoryspecificredDotUID=00000002KJ).  You could bond wires (and components) to fabric with a conductive glue and use any other paintable conductive material that remains flexible after drying to lay out a circuit.  The printing/painting resolution probably wouldn't be great so circuit complexity and density would be constrained, but I see no obvious reason why it couldn't work.